# Amazon web services CLI Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.ec2-east.amazonaws.com/" is throwing

Comment: You need to put a bit of context in your question, what are you doing ? (command entered) and what you expect ....

Comment: If I entered aws ec2 describe-instances and it throwing error like above mentioned

Comment: This is not enough info, try pasting the entire script and the entire error in the question.. you can (and should) mask the credentials if they show up in the script.

Comment: I am trying to configure to aws cli on windows on that I installed awscli tool and then in commad prompt if we type aws configure.... then it asking the access key and private key. I am giving the same then asking type username then giving my user name and then json format file i am giving. Then am typing the aws ec2(username) describe-instances and hit enter....... then it throwing the same error which i  mentioned in above

Answer (score 0):

You do not use a valid region (`ec2-east`)

For ec2 regions, please refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region

Your command should be `aws ec2 describe-instances --region xxx` where xxx is in the list from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region like `aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1`

Comment: thanks, please make sure to [accept the answer if valid](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)